# QGIS processing scripts, more than one progress bar in the generated GUI?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, pyqt, gui

Since I sometimes have to process cross product of two vector layers with geoprocessing scripts, causing me to use nested loops like

```
source_count = source_layer.featureCount()
target_count = target_layer.featureCount()
nsource = 1.0
for f_source in source_layer.getFeatures():
    ntarget = 1.0
    for f_target in target_layer.getFeatures():
        #do something
        targetprogress = 100 * (ntarget / target_count)
        ntarget += 1
    sourceprogress = 100  *(nsource / source_count)
    progress.setPercentage(sourceprogress)
    nsource += 1
```

When both layers consist of, let's say, some ten thousands of features, processing can be extremely time consuming, and to communicate the user that the processing is still alive, it would make sense to have a progress bar for each inner and outer loop.

I don't think this can be achieved with standard processing gui tools, but this combined with some `Qt` widgets? I'd like to do the processing in a script, not a plugin, in wich's `Qt` form various `QprogressBars` would be easy to implement.

Comment: Can't you import what is necessary into your script?   

from PyQt4.QtGui import QProgressBar
from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar
  
or something like this and then use it?
iface.messageBar().pushWidget(QProgressBar(), QgsMessageBar().INFO, 0)

Comment: Quite helpful workaround. So now I have two progress bars, one in the scripts automatically generated gui and one in the message bar. Gives nice and entertaining screen animations for my nested loops ;-) @Victor consider to add this as an answer!

Comment: But beware! Updating a progress bar in the inner loop is extremely time consuming and slows down processing significantly! Perhaps two progress bars in such cases doesn't belong to the top 100 ideas I ever had... @Victor: possibly add this warning to you answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could import the necessary functions into your script with:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QProgressBar
from qgis.gui import QgsMessageBar
```

Then you can call the progress bar with:

```
msgBar= iface.messageBar()
pb= QProgressBar()
msgBar.pushWidget(pb, QgsMessageBar().INFO, 0)
```

and update the value in the progress bar in your loop:

```
pb.setValue(Your_variable)
```

However, as you pointed out, updating a progress bar in your inner loop can slow down the process.
Cheers,